# Elixir Ecto.Schema error: __schema__/1 undefined

Tags: model, elixir, ecto

I'm currently facing an error that I flat out do not understand--it's a symptom of something and I don't know conceptually what it might be. Here's what I think is the relevant code.

In my model definition, I have:

```
defmodule EventBridge.Event do
  use Ecto.Schema
  use Timex.Ecto.Timestamps

  import Ecto
  import Ecto.Changeset

  alias Timex.Parse.DateTime.Parser

  schema "events" do
    field :occurred_at, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
    field :action, :string
    field :source_application, :string
    field :athlete_id, :integer
    field :coach_id, :integer
    field :detail, :string
    field :deleted, :integer, default: 0
    field :deleted_at, Timex.Ecto.DateTime
    field :partner_name, :string, default: "Source Partner 1"
    field :coach_email, :string
    field :coach_first_name, :string
    field :coach_last_name, :string
    field :coach_position, :string
    field :college_name, :string
    field :athlete_email, :string
    field :athlete_first_name, :string
    field :athlete_last_name, :string
    field :coach_sport, :map, default: %{}
    field :athlete_sport, :map, default: %{}
  end

  ...
end
```

Here is the place where the error comes from:

```
defmodule EventBridge.Migrate.ProducerConsumer do
  use GenStage

  import Ecto.Query
  import Ecto.Changeset
  import Ecto.Query, only: [from: 1, from: 2]

  alias EventBridge.CoachActivityRepo
  alias EventBridge.Event
  alias EventBridge.C3poEvent
  alias EventBridge.SportsMap
  alias EventBridge.TimeUtils

  def start_link do
    GenStage.start_link(__MODULE__, :state_doesnt_matter, name: __MODULE__)
  end

  def init(number) do
    {:producer_consumer, number}
  end

  def handle_events(events, _from, number) do
    changesets = Enum.map(events, fn(event) ->
      transform_event(event)
    end)
    |> List.flatten()

    {:noreply, changesets, number}
  end

  #==========
  defp transform_event(%C3poEvent{action: "search appearance"} = c3po_event), do: search_appearance_event(c3po_event)
  defp transform_event(%C3poEvent{action: "view"} = c3po_event), do: view_event(c3po_event)
  defp transform_event(c3po_event), do: nil
  #==========

  defp single_event(c3po_event) do
    ...
  end

  defp search_appearance_event(c3po_event) do
    counter = real_count(c3po_event)

    case counter do
      x when x > 0 ->
        create_search_appearance_events(c3po_event, counter, [])
      x when x < 0 ->
        delete_search_appearance_events(c3po_event, counter)
      _ ->
        []
    end
  end

  defp delete_search_appearance_events(c3po_event, counter) do
    from(t in CoachActivityRepo,      # ERROR FROM HERE
      where: t.athlete_id == ^c3po_event.athlete_id,
      where: t.coach_id == ^c3po_event.coach_id,
      where: t.action == 'search appearance',
      order_by: [desc: t.occurred_at],
      limit: ^counter,
      offset: 0)
    |> CoachActivityRepo.delete_all
    []
  end

  defp create_search_appearance_events(c3po_event, counter, accumulator) do
    ...
  end

  defp shifted_datetime(days) do
    ...
  end

  defp view_event(c3po_event) do
    ...
  end

  defp convert_event_parameters(c3po_event, occurred_at) do
    ...
  end
  defp convert_event_parameters(c3po_event) do
    ...
  end

  defp real_count(c3po_event) do
    c3po_event - from(t in CoachActivityRepo,  # ERROR FROM HERE
      select: count(t.id),
      where: t.athlete_id == ^c3po_event.athlete_id,
      where: t.coach_id == ^c3po_event.coach_id,
      where: t.action == 'search appearance')
  end
end
```

This is the Repo definition:

```
defmodule EventBridge.CoachActivityRepo do
 use Ecto.Repo, otp_app: :event_bridge
end
```

I suspect this is too much information. I'm not looking for the Right Code here, I mostly want to know if anyone can describe what causes the original error in the case of a model being used. Do my

Comment: Umm, is `CoachActivityRepo` a Repo? You need to put a schema module there.

Comment: yes, I'll add the definition of the repo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ecto queries work on modules with Ecto.Schema inside, not on Ecto.Repo.

You should do as following:

```
from e in EventBridge.Event...
```

Repo is just a module that communicates with DB via DB engine's adapter.

Comment: That got it. Thanks! Now I feel kind of stupid, but at the same time vastly relieved.